# How can I automate file inclusion using arguments?

Tags: input, automation, multiple-files

I am working on a collection of books that uses content from other files. I want to have each reference in a file to avoid redundant content and to make it easier to review and correct the content.

Let me explain, I have created a file for each reference number, for example:

```
CEC/n/0001.tex
CEC/n/0002.tex
CEC/n/0003.tex
CEC/n/0004.tex
CEC/n/0005.tex
CEC/n/0006.tex
CEC/n/0007.tex
....
CEC/n/9999.tex
```

Suppose in a part of one of my books I need to include **the numbers 1 to 5, the number 22 and the number 17**. I am currently doing the following, which works:

```
\input{../../CEC/n/0001}

\input{../../CEC/n/0002}

\input{../../CEC/n/0003}

\input{../../CEC/n/0004}

\input{../../CEC/n/0005}

\input{../../CEC/n/0022}

\input{../../CEC/n/0017}
```

Is there a way to simplify it?

My idea is to be able to receive an array of numbers `[1,2,3,4,5,22,17]` or `[1 to 5 AND 22 AND 17]` and use it to include each of those files by their names? I need to include many reference combinations like above in different parts of my volumes and I want to simplify this task.

I'm sorry I can't create a minimal, verifiable example due to file inclusion.

Comment: It many of these cases it is better to use an external program to generate the source code for you. For example via python or similar. It is a lot easier to provide command line interface for those than it is for latex and friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following set of macros does the job, provided the file names have a common structure. The main command is

```
\multiinput{<prefix>}{<format>}{<list>}[<post action>]
```

In your case it would be

```
\multiinput{../../CEC/n/}{0000}{1-5,22,17}
```

Code, where in the second case I added `\par` as the post action to be performed when the file has been input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\multiinput}{mmm+O{}}
 {% #1 = fixed part
  % #2 = format for the variable part
  % #3 = list
  % #4 = post action
  \cedano_multiinput:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__cedano_multiinput_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l__cedano_multiinput_interval_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cedano_multiinput:nnnn
 {
  % split the list at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__cedano_multiinput_items_seq {,} { #3 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__cedano_multiinput_items_seq
   {
    \__cedano_multiinput_item:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { ##1 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cedano_multiinput_item:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__cedano_multiinput_interval_seq { - } { #3 }
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__cedano_multiinput_interval_seq = 1 }
   {% just one item
    \__cedano_multiinput_file:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {% multiple files
    \int_step_inline:nnn
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__cedano_multiinput_interval_seq { 1 } } % start
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__cedano_multiinput_interval_seq { 2 } } % end
     { \__cedano_multiinput_file:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { ##1 } { #4 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cedano_multiinput_file:nnnn
 {
  \file_input:n { #1 \__cedano_multiinput_pad:nn { #2 } { #3 } } #4
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__cedano_multiinput_pad:nn
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } - \tl_count:n { #2 } } { 0 } #2
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textbf{From 1 to 10}

\multiinput{inputs/}{0000}{1-10}

\bigskip

\textbf{Selection}

\multiinput{inputs/}{0000}{1-2,4,7,9-10}[\par]

\end{document}
```

I created in the subdirectory `inputs` the files `0001.tex` to `0010.tex` that contain

```
I'm number XXXX
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be just what I need, but I can't make it work. I have reproduced same code, creating the files in an `input` folder but it doesn't recognize the commands... *! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \ExplSyntaxOn*  and *! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \NewDocumentCommand {\multiinput}{mmm+O{}}* with the message: *The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined*

Comment: @A.Cedano In this case you need to add `\usepackage{xparse}`

Comment: I added that and I'm having the same error. If I try only this `\multiinput{inputs/}{0000}{1-10}`and I open the PDF generated, i have one line: `110`  and if I try only this: `\multiinput{inputs/}{0000}{1-2,4,7,9-10}[\par]`  the PDF have these lines: `12`  and `I’m number 0004` and `I’m number 0007` and `910` in both cases the error *`Undefined control sequence persists`*

Comment: @A.Cedano What TeX system are you using and which release?

Comment: I'm using: `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`  into Ubuntu 18. The IDE I'm using is `TeXstudio 3.1.2`

Comment: @A.Cedano Sorry, but that TeX Live is really outdated.

Comment: I have everything updated using this command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`  Is there any other way to update to the latest version of TexLive?

Comment: @A.Cedano https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/4427